# Testing for no data found in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm just starting to test using Postman.  I need to add a test to verify that my API handles no data found successfully (it's designed to return an empty array rather than give a standard error).  My API Person control is returning:

```
{
  "value": []
}
```

But I've failed to find a way to test for this in Postman (I'm new to javascript having tested in selenium and c# up to now).  I've tried:

```
tests["No persons found"] = data.Person === 0;
```

without success.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Chrissi

Comment: Does **Person** refer to 

{
  "value": []
}

Comment: Yes, Person is the control.

Comment: Can you post the entire response returned by your controller, incase there is more of it

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var list = (data.Person || {}).value;
tests["No persons found"] = list === undefined || list.length === 0;
```